# CSS variable-height cutout over fixed image backdrop

Tags: html, css

The following code simulates a cutout through an opaque background, scrolling over a fixed image underneath.  The height of the cutout is dynamic, sizing to fit its content.

**Problem:** The code uses a terrible hack!  Notice the content *Y* of the cutout is duplicated in the HTML, though only displayed once in the visual output.

The thing is--the hack "works".  Both duplicates are necessary:

- If the first is removed, the remaining content *Y* renders behind the image, no longer visible.
- If the second is removed, the cutout collapses to a height of zero, and the remaining content *Y* overlaps content *Z*.

**Question:** Is there a better alternative to this hack, in pure CSS?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Simulated Backdrop Image Cutout through Opaque Background</title>
  <style>
   .opaque-background {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
   }
   
   .container {
    position: relative;
   }
   
   .cutout {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTFBR.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body class="opaque-background">
  Content preceding (X)
  <div class="container">
   <div class="cutout">
   Content between (Y)
   </div>
   Content between (Y)
  </div>
  Content following (Z)
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boy do I feel sheepish.  The answer is as simple as adjusting the z-index so the cutout renders behind the content *Y*.  (I thought I had already tried that, but apparently not.)

```
.cutout {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTFBR.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

The HTML:

```
Content preceding (X)
<div class="container">
    <div class="cutout">
    </div>
    Content between (Y)
</div>
Content following (Z)
```